# Salesforce dev org too slow

Tags: deployment, developer-console, ide, mavensmate, developer-org

My salesforce org is too slow all of a sudden and is timing out randomly. Due to this am not able to save files or deploy using mavensmate or force.com IDE. The connection to the server is just hanging.

I'm not sure how to debug the issue as I can't find any logs for the background commands running. Any pointers as to how to debug this?

Comment: Are you on EU1, EU2 or EU3? [trust.salesforce.com](https://status.salesforce.com/status) says they're experiencing problems currently.

Comment: Nope. I'm not on those instances. I'm on NA instances which seem healthy.

Comment: Dev Orgs are at the bottom of the priority chain when it comes to resources. This happens, just as it happens to sandboxes. Production Orgs are given the highest priority.

Comment: NA4 by any chance? https://status.salesforce.com/status/NA4/incidents/1000

Comment: These orgs have become extremely slow in syncing to server and are timing out for most requests. They were never this slow. I'm not able to save anything or get deployments to work. Since both Mavensmate and Force.com IDE have issues with the APIs, I was hoping this would be a performance issue. But the trust site does not report any issue on the servers. I'm on NA35 and NA40. Unsure where to find some resolution

Comment: NA35 has/had major issues and all new sign ups were moved to NA40. MDAPI requests on NA35 were taking anywhere from 10-90 minutes to complete (simple save of a file). It is a nightmare. Now other orgs are experiencing it. Tooling API used to be the cure but now even that is slow. Lightning saves always happened quickly and were never affected. Unfortunately there is not much you can do if you do not have access to premier support or the partner community. Or you could have a completely different issue

Comment: FYI - SF is aware of the issues and you are not alone and you should report it if you can. Not sure on their errors or prioritization of any resolution though. And these issue will not show up on Trust (per comments from SF in partner community) so you are left just pulling your hair out.

Comment: @Eric, Thanks for your response. NA35 is indeed very slow. I moved to an org in NA40 and it is a tad bit better. I have logged a case with salesforce support and have read through some of the posts on partner community. It seems like this issue has been there for a couple of months. I wonder why it does not get reported on Trust, it is frustrating to try to debug such issues.

Comment: @Brian - Here is a link to a few threads in the Partner community: https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A00002znWpN and https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A00002oannH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesfroce has a Knowledge article precising the steps to follow for this kind of issues. Additionally, as pointed out by @crmprogdev, salesforce allocates resources in highest priorities to production orgs.

Steps to follow as pointed by the kb [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213798&type=1):

> ## [How to Diagnose Network Issues](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213798&type=1)
>
> **Knowledge Article Number**
>   000213798
>
> 1. Check Trust status [here](https://status.salesforce.com/status)
> 2. Ask your colleagues if they are also experiencing a slow connection.
> 3. Run a Ping to Salesforce
> 4. Run a Traceroute to Salesforce
> 5. Look for odd routing decisions and node specific issues.
> 6. Contact Salesforce Support

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I checked that my connectivity to salesforce orgs works fine. The metadata APIs on the orgs however are extremely slow..

Comment: Yes, this happens from time to time, specially with dev orgs. don't forget to accept the answer and or up vote if this was helpfull, cheers!